# JSF primefaces convertDateTime pattern year for the year 2020 is incorrect

Tags: datetime, jsf, primefaces, format, converters

Issue with the pattern year 2020

In the calendar popup it is selected as  is but upon selection it is set as 3/29/20

The value gets stored as  29-MAR-20 in the database

Data type of date2 is DATE in the database

But the outputText value shows it as 03/29/**0020**.

Correct output text should be 03/20/**2020**

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" skipDetailIfEqualsSummary="true" />

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">

        <p:outputLabel for="popup" value="Popup:" />
        <p:calendar id="popup" value="#{calendarView.date2}" />

    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="msgs" action="#{calendarView.click}" icon="pi pi-check" />

    <p:dialog modal="true" resizable="false" header="Values" widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fold">
        <p:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" columnClasses="label,value">

            <h:outputText value="Popup:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{calendarView.date2}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
            </h:outputText>

        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

web.xml

```
        <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
        </context-param>
```

Tested with the date selection of 6/27/99

The value gets stored as  27-JUN-99 in the database

The output was shown as expected / correct out put - 06/27/1999

Comment: Are you really saying that it works fine when you use System.out.println() instead of JSF to present the model from the database? If not then it's not a JSF problem and you need to take a step back and reframe your question to focus on the way how you save and retrive values in DB.

Comment: I have just added pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" into <p:calendar id="popup" value="#{calendarView.date2}" />   My issue was resolved